# Haskell Parsec combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string

Tags: parsing, haskell, runtime-error, parsec

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

delimiter :: Parser ()
delimiter = do char '|'
               return ()
          <?> "delimiter"


eol :: Parser ()
eol = do oneOf "\n\r"
         return ()
    <?> "end of line"

item :: Parser String
item = do entry <- manyTill anyChar (try eol <|> try delimiter <|> eof)
          return entry

items :: Parser [String]
items = do result <- many item
           return result
```

When I run `parseTest items "a|b|c"` with the code above I get the following error:

```
*** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: 
combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.
```

I believe it has something to do with `eof` and `many item`, if I remove `eof`, then I can get it to work as long as the line does not end in `eof`, which makes it kind of useless.

I realize I could just use `sepBy` but what I am interested in is why this code does not work and how to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A parser like `many` can indeed not be applied to parsers that accept the empty string, because this makes the grammar ambiguous: How often do you parse the empty string? Choosing different numbers can lead to different parse results ...

You are right to assume that `many item` is the problematic combination. An `item` is defined in terms of `manyTill`. (Excursion: Btw, you can simplify `manyTill` to

```
item :: Parser String
item = manyTill anyChar (eol <|> delimiter <|> eof)
```

No need for the `do` or the `return`, and no need for `try`, because each of the three parsers
expect different first tokens.) The parser `manyTill` thus parses an arbitrary number of characters, followed by either an `eol`, a `delimiter`, or an `eof`. Now, `eol` and `delimiter` actually consume at least one character when they succeed, but `eof` doesn't. The parser `eof` succeeds at the end of the input, but it can be applied multiple times. For example,

```
ghci> parseTest (do { eof; eof }) ""
()
```

It doesn't consume any input, and is thereby making it possible for `item` to succeed on the empty string (at the end of your input), and is thereby causing the ambiguity.

To fix this, you can indeed rewrite your grammar and move to something like `sepBy`, or you can try to distinguish normal `item`s (where `eof` isn't allowed as end-marker) from the final `item` (where `eof` is allowed).

Comment: One hacky way, is to prepend newline to the input (if there aren't any) and drop eof from the grammar.

Comment: Great! Knowing that eof does not consume anything makes it clear why it does not work. Realistically I will just use sepBy, but I'll try to use the final item idea just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: @OlegGrenrus Well, `\n` is already allowed as a delimiter. So if you do this, you have to be careful that you're not getting an extra empty item in the end. It's certainly possible to do it in this way or in others, but you'll always have to take care you don't change the semantics.

Comment: @kosmikus: The parser will not accept `""` after newline, as it will need a terminator after each one.

Comment: @OlegGrenrus No, but if you already have a `\n` at the end of the input, and then add another one, you'll get an additional empty item that perhaps you didn't want. Ok, I now see that this is what you meant when you said "if there aren't any". I had misinterpreted that, sorry.

Comment: @kosmikus: is to append newline to the input *(if there aren't any)*

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is an infinite number of ways to parse an empty string as `many emptyString`

Comment: Is that because it would go on infinitely? What is a good solution to the problem then?

Comment: That's a good point, haha. Anyway, kosmikus mentioned adding a special final item which is the idea I was looking for.