# Parsec, read text ended by a string

Tags: haskell, parsec, blaze-html

I am struggling with `Parsec` to parse a small subset of the [Google project wiki syntax](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax), and convert it into HTML. My syntax is limited to text sequences and item lists. Here is an example of what I want to recognize:

```
Text that can contain any kind of characters,
except the string "\n *"
 * list item 1
 * list item 2

End of list
```

My code so far is:

```
import Text.Blaze.Html5 (Html, toHtml)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)

parseList :: Parser Html
parseList = do
    items <- many1 parseItem
    return $ H.ul $ sequence_ items

parseItem :: Parser Html
parseItem = do
    string "\n *"
    item <- manyTill anyChar $
        (try $ lookAhead $ string "\n *") <|>
        (try $ string "\n\n")
    return $ H.li $ toHtml item

parseText :: Parser Html
parseText = do
    text <- manyTill anyChar $
        (try $ lookAhead $ string "\n *") <|>
        (eof >> (string ""))
    return $ toHtml text

parseAll :: Parser Html
parseAll = do
    l <- many (parseUl <|> parseText)
    return $ H.html $ sequence_ l
```

When applying `parseAll` to any sequence of characters, I get the following error message: `"*** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.`
I understand that it is because my parser `parseText` can read empty strings, but I can't see any other way. How can I recognize text delimited by a string? (`"\n *"` here).

I am also open to any remarks or suggestions concerning the way I am using Parsec. I can't help but see that my code is a bit ugly. Can I do all this in a simpler way? For example, there is code replication (which is kind of painful) because of the string `"\n *"`, that is used to recognize the end of a text sequence, the beginning of a list item, AND the end of a list item...

Comment: Does `sepEndBy1 (string " *" >> many (noneOf "\n")) (string "\n")` do what you want? It seems to me that is the language you are describing is just a string containing many lines started by a " *". In which case you don't even need parsec: `map (\(' ':'*':x) -> x) . lines`

Comment: A list item could contain newlines and stars as well, the true separator for list items is "\n *".

Comment: The only 'illegal' sequences are strings, not chars ("\n *" and "\n\n"). That's why noneOf won't work. And I still need a way to parse text that could appear before a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parseItem :: Parser String
parseItem = do
    manyTill anyChar $
        (try $ lookAhead $ string "\n *") <|>
        (try $ string "\n\n")

parseText :: Parser [String]
parseText = 
  string "\n *" >> -- remove this if text *can't* contain a leading '\n *'
  sepBy1 parseItem (string "\n *")
```

I removed the HTML stuff because for whatever reason I couldn't get `blaze-html` to install on my machine. But in principle it should be essentially the same thing. This parses strings delimited by the string "\n *" and ended by the string "\n\n". I don't know if have a leading `\n` is what you want but that is easy to fix.

Also, I don't know if the empty string is valid. You should change `sepBy1` to `sepBy` if it is.

As for the error you were getting: you have `string ""` inside of `many`. Not only does this give the error you got, it doesn't make any sense! The parser `string ""` will always succeed without consuming anything, since the empty string is a prefix of all strings and `"" ++ x == x`. If you try to do this multiple times then you will never finish parsing.

Besides all that, your `parseList` should parse your language. It essentially does the same thing that `sepBy` does. I just think `sepBy` is cleaner :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the tip with `sepBy`. The problem, though, isn't to recognize a list (parseList does the job), but to recognize text that can appear before the list, and that can contain any character. I don't think `eof >> string ""` is a problem, it reads `end of file` and then the empty string. I did that because `eof` is of the wrong type (I should have written `eof >> return ""`).

Comment: If you remove `string "\n *" >>` then this parser will accept any text not containing "\n *" before parsing the list items. So `parse parseText "" "Text \n * item 1 \n * item 2 \n\n" == Right ["Text "," item 1 "," item 2 "]`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: My mistake, you are right. And I just need to add the separator `"\n\n"` (and a small `lookAhead` inside of `parseItem`), and I can even read text after a list. I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899931/haskell-parsec-combinator-many-is-applied-to-a-parser-that-accepts-an-empty-st), which is a problem very close to mine, and they advise him to use `sepBy` as well.

Comment: If you want to have an additional text block after "\n\n" you can do the following: `parseMoreText = do {a <- parseText; b <- many anyChar; return $ a ++ [b]}`. Then you can accept a string like `"Text \n * item 1 \n * item 2 \n\n more text"`. And yes, in general you should always scour the libraries for a combinator that does what you want before even attempting to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `manyTill` combinator matches zero or more anyChar. Just change parseText to match at least one anyChar, so that it fails when reading one of the separators - unfortunately there is no `many1Till` combinator.

Also I prefer `parseAll = fmap (H.html . sequence) $ many (parseUl <|> parseText)`, since you mentioned ugliness tips.

```
parseText = do
               notFollowedBy $ string "\n *"
               first <- anyChar
               rest <- manyTill anyChar $
                       (try $ lookAhead $ string "\n *") <|>
                       (eof >> (string ""))
               return $ toHtml first:rest

parseAll = fmap (H.html . sequence) $ many (parseUl <|> parseText)
```

That said, "parseUl" on google gives only this question so I don't know a better solution without understanding that parser.

---

Desperate for my first accepted answer, I wrote it out in full :) just add the html stuff on top with fmap (preferred) or return.

```
module Main where
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)

parseList :: Parser [String]
parseList = many1 parseItem

parseItem :: Parser String
parseItem = string "\n *" >> (manyTill anyChar $ try $ lookAhead $ char '\n')

parseText :: Parser String
parseText = do
               notFollowedBy $ string "\n *" 
               first <- anyChar
               rest <- manyTill anyChar $
                   (try $ lookAhead $  string "\n *") <|>
                   (eof >> (string ""))
               return $ first:rest

parseAll :: Parser [String]
parseAll = many $ parseText <|> fmap concat parseList

parseIt :: String -> String
parseIt input = case parse parseAll "wiki" input of
    Left err -> "No match: " ++ show err
    Right val -> "It worked"

main = do
          args <- getArgs
          putStrLn (parseIt (args !! 0))
```

I assumed lists can't contain newlines, but the `try $ lookahead $ char '\n'` is easily tweaked. You can factor out `string "\n *"` to avoid duplication. Here I crushed all the lists and ignored the parse with sequence, but you'll have to cahnge that. It would all be simpler if you divided the "text" into lines of text and then just check for either a line of text or a line from a list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and your effort! I accept the other answer though, because his solution is shorter, and he was quicker. Your idea for `parseText` might indeed be useful.
By the way, `parseItem` doesn't work as it is, I had to change it by: `string "\n *" >> (many $ noneOf "\n")`.

Comment: worked for me `(many $ noneOf "\n")` is much better (and the same thing) - I agree to prefer the short solution, but a word of warning - his parseText is actually parseList, so you will still have the problem of parseText matching an empty string, and causing an exception when used in `many ... <|> parseText` so this will get very messy...

Comment: whoops -- i wanted to edit to  - I agree to prefer the short solution, but a word of warning - this will get very messy... (best to separate these things somehow since you are probably adding other parses, and the other parse only allows text before and doesn't say what is and isn't items :(